# How to capture line using regexp match and find out whether it is present or not in a line and additionally group it

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to replace a string into a line that mathes with another set of strings as given below

### Regex:

```
- replace: 
    path: /etc/pam.d/system-auth
    regexp: '^(password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*)( remember=\d+)(.*)$'
    replace: '\1\3 remember=8'
```

### Desired match:

```
password  sufficient  pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok              <<< my regex not works! 
password  sufficient  pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok remember=7   <<< works!
password  sufficient  pam_unix.so sha512 shadow remember=8 nullok try_first_pass use_authtok   <<< works!
```

and I want to replace it to

```
password  sufficient  pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok remember=8
```

How can I find out if it exists or not at one go(possibly within a single line).
Thank you.
I am using Ansible.
ps. I'm not good at English, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 capturing groups and make the last 2 capturing groups optional as the remember part followed by the digits and what might follow are not guaranteed to be there.

You can add a word boundary `\b` after matching the digits for remember to prevent the match being part of a larger word.

```
^(password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so.*?)(?:( remember=\d+\b)(.*))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9PXQ2t/1)